# Relative imports of files from same folder are edited in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, eslint, webstorm

Whenever I am working in my project and move around some files the imports are being changes in my html.

For example when I have a folder navigation in which I have 2 files, one of the files points to the other file in the same folder. In this case WebStorm removes the `./` from the `import src`. Anyone know how to fix this?

Could this be a ESLint config issue? How would I go about fixing it?